# Issue with BuildConfig.FLAVOR after Android Studio 3.6 update

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-configchanges, android-gradle-3.0

Anyone experiencing issues with `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` parameter? After **Android Studio 3.6** update all of my `BuildConfig` usages in code were red (as if the import was removed) and I can't override it from app config, only from `Crashlytics` and other sources. It has critical functionality in my app to load the right URL for API calls based on different flavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `Build -> Clean Project` and then `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`. It was still red after rebuilding, but as I build my App on smartphone it suddenly worked and red color disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reganerate all auto generate files of gradle again.

Build -> Run Generate Sources Gradle Tasks